# Failed to start CloudWatch agent on ubuntu22.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Software package download

```
wget https://amazoncloudwatch-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/arm64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
```

amazon-cloudwatch-agent version

```
 /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status
{
  "status": "stopped",
  "starttime": "",
  "configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.300032.2b361"
}
```

Run the installation command

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m onPremise -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json

` processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent 2024/01/08 09:45:20 E! Failed to open Common Config: open /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml: no such file or directory``
```

No errors occurred while installing the software. There is only one empty directory amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d in the etc directory. After manually editing the configuration file amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json and starting the agent, an error is reported that there is no "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml" file. Is there a problem with this agent version?

Even if I use the wizard, the /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml file is not generated. Does this version not have these configuration files by default?

Comment: Have you tried with below link ? Try to put region-name.



https://amazoncloudwatch-agent-<region>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb

Comment: I've tried it and it's the same

Comment: Did you attach instance role with EC2 ? If not then try to uninstall cloudwatch agent package and reinstall it.

Comment: Various reinstallations have not worked, I have configured both files manually